# Programmatically add user to programmatically created database (Azure SQL)

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

I'm using Azure Management ResourceManager to programmatically create a database on an Azure SQL Server.
This works fine.
I use:

```
var azureCredentials = new AzureCredentials(new ServicePrincipalLoginInformation
{
    ClientId = ClientID,
    ClientSecret = ClientSecret,
}, TenantID, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var newDB = azure.SqlServers.Databases.Define(DatabaseName)
    .WithExistingSqlServer(ResourceGroupName, SqlServerName, Region.EuropeWest.Name)
    .WithEdition(DatabaseEdition.Standard)
    .WithServiceObjective(ServiceObjectiveName.S1)                    
    .Create();
```

Now I want to add a login to the master database, and a user based on that login to the created database. 
However, I seem to be unable to do this completely programmatically. 
I have an app registration that I use to get a token, but when I try to create ac connection with an SqlConnection using the token, I get an error: 
`Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'.` 
According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell) I first need to add the user to the database, using T-SQL:

```
CREATE USER [<Azure_AD_principal_name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

But I can't do this programmatically without having a connection to the database first!

Is there no way to do this completely automated??

Cheers,
CJ

Comment: Since you're on an existing SQL server it would be easiest to use the server admin of that server to do the modifications on the database.

In the SQL server in the azure portal you can go to properties to see the server admin login and under overview you can reset the password.

Comment: Yeah, I just remembered that myself.. Very stupid... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got so caught up in app registrations and tokens, I completely forgot that I also have a server admin account for the databaser server..
Stupid me...